# How to set uk format on datepicker using angular 5 bootstrap datepicker

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm an trying to set uk format to the date after it has been selected.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="test_StartDate" class="col-md-12">{{l("StartDate")}}</label>
    <input *ngIf="!test.id" class="form-control m-input" type="datetime" name="test_StartDate" datePicker [(selectedDate)]="test.startDate" id="test_StartDate">
    <input *ngIf="test.id" 
           class="form-control m-input" 
           type="datetime" 
           name="test_StartDate" 
           datePicker
           [(selectedDate)]="test.startDate" 
           id="test_StartDate"
           data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY">
</div>
```

Output: 01/12/2019

Should be: 12/01/2019

Answer (score 1):

using Angular 10+

You can set the locale on the provider in your module:
Just add the following:

```
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

...

```
providers: [
{
    provide: LOCALE_ID,
    useValue: 'gb'
},...]
```

sample HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="datetime" [matDatepicker]="startDate" 
           placeholder="Choose a date">
         <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDate">
         </mat-datepicker-toggle>
         <mat-datepicker #startDate ></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB4PY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, add format to date picker configuration options

```js
$("#test_StartDate").datepicker({ 
        autoclose: true, 
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        todayHighlight: true
  }).datepicker('update', new Date());
```

```css
#test_StartDate{
  width:150px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="test_StartDate" class="col-md-12">{{l("StartDate")}}</label>
    <input *ngIf="!test.id" class="form-control m-input" type="datetime" name="test_StartDate" datePicker [(selectedDate)]="test.startDate" id="test_StartDate">
    <input *ngIf="test.id" 
           class="form-control m-input" 
           type="datetime" 
           name="test_StartDate" 
           datePicker
           [(selectedDate)]="test.startDate" 
           id="test_StartDate"
           data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY">
</div>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ROxjrY

Comment: I have "bootstrap4-datetimepicker": "^5.2.3", included in the package.json file is the code transferable?

Comment: yes @nless, you just need to provide the format through options - http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/